# Move CKRecords from development to production

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have got thousands of CKRecords in the development environment I need moved to the production envrionment.

I found this answer: *There is no easy way to migrate your records. You cannot link an app both to production and to development. The only workaround is downloading all records from development and storing those records in a file and then switch to production and upload the contents of that file to production.*

What i understand of this is: I need a new app where I query all of my records in the development environment and save them to a file. Then I need to submit this app in order for it to connect to the production environment. I then upload/save the records of this file to the production environment. But how do I save my records in a file?

Comment: You don't need to submit a new app, you can build an ad-hoc IPA that connects to the production environment and install this on your device using Xcode or iTunes. As far as saving your data, you could use Core Data, a plist file, a text file, anything really.

Comment: Hi Paulw11. Thanks for answering. But how do I save a CKRecord in Core Data? I want to save it right after querying it.

Comment: There is no direct method; you need to access each field from your CKRecord and put it into a Core Data entity.